# After a query, calling getInt on the cursor force closes my app

Tags: android, sqlite

```
private static final String Memo_ID = "_ID";
```

This is my create table code, there is no problem

```
private static final String MemoDB_CREATE = "create table Memo (_ID integer primary key autoincrement, MemoName text, MemoPW text, MainType text, SecType text, MainID text, SecID text)";
```

.

```
db.execSQL(MemoDB_CREATE);
```

Here is query code. I've got force close because getInt Method

```
openDB();
String[] col = new String[] {Memo_ID};
Cursor c = db.query(Memo_Table, col, null, null, null, null, null);
int[] result = new int[c.getCount()-1];     
if(c.moveToFirst()){
     for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++){
          result[i] = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Memo_ID));
          c.moveToNext();
     }//end of for
}               
c.close();
db.close();
```

i want all of id in id column that why i put null into third parameter of query method

my log cat http://upic.me/i/oe/80untitled.jpg

Comment: What exception are you getting exactly?

Comment: i dont write any exception code ;(

Comment: What's in the logcat when you get the force close?

Comment: If you get a force close, LogCat is able to tell you why.
I noticed something though, right here: `result[i] = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Memo_ID));`   You refer to `Memo_ID`, is that a variable or is that the column you're trying to access? If it's the latter, you should put quotes around it. `getColumnIndex()` takes `String` variables.

Comment: my logcat http://upic.me/i/oe/80untitled.jpg

Comment: private static final String Memo_ID = "_ID";
Memo_ID is String variable of column name

Comment: Your LogCat shows an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` exception. On what line is it giving this exception? Double click the line with the error in LogCat and Eclipse will show you what's on that line.

Comment: result[i] = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(Memo_ID)); /// Ecllipse highlight this line

Comment: do you think this is reason why i get force code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8463377/why-cant-i-open-my-db-with-sqlite-manager-in-eclipse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either remove the -1 from

```
int[] result = new int[c.getCount()-1];
```

or add it to

```
for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++){
```

after the c.getCount():

```
for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount() - 1; i++){
```

I don't know what your intention is so can't tell you which one is best, but I suspect you need to remove the -1 from the array declaration. If not, watch out for negative size array exceptions when the query returns zero results! c.getCount() - 1 will result in -1, and you can't have an array of size -1.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
int[] result = new int[c.getCount()-1];
```

To:

```
int[] result = new int[c.getCount()];`
```

Answer (score 0):

From the logcat, you may have a column not found problem. Is there definitely a `Memo_ID` column?

Comment: there is a _ID column ,, Memo_ID is string variable of _ID column
///////////  private static final String Memo_ID = "_ID";

Comment: Could you get the logcat again but expand the column before the screengrab so the text is all visible.